# JQuery Submit Button not working second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When i click on submit button , it work for first time  then show success alert but second time submit button not working. Need refresh/reload the page again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#submit').click(function(){
   var data = $("#formdata").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        method: "POST",
        data: data,

        success:function(data){
                $('#alert').addClass("alert alert-success").text(data).fadeOut(3000);           
        }
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: Try `$('#alert').show().addClass("alert alert-success").text(data).fadeOut(3000); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:-

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
```

Use

```
$("#formdata").on('submit',function(e){ 

//or you can use $(document).on('click','#submit',function(e){

e.preventDefault();//rest code
```

Also change alert message like below:-

```
$('#alert').addClass("alert alert-success").text(data).fadeIn().fadeOut(3000);
```

Comment: Thank u So much 
without 'click' its not working . then i added this 
now its working well

$(document).on('click','#submit',function(e)